# JMeter - SHH Command - How to set PATH and initial folder for all samplers

Tags: linux, unix, path, jmeter, ssh-tunnel

I set up a test on my MacOS machine by using SSH sampler and send Linux commands trough it. But for every sampler I need to set the PATH variable and cd to the needed folder for my commands individually on every sampler.

How can I do this generally/globally, so that it is not needed to do the following commands on every SHH command sampler:

`cd path/to/folder; export PATH=path/folder:PATH`

When I execute env command I'm seeing the following output:

> USER=mac_user
> LOGNAME=mac_user
> HOME=/Users/mac_user
> PATH=/Users/mac_user/projects/dpp2/cli/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
> SHELL=/bin/zsh
> SSH_CLIENT=127.0.0.1 54804 22
> SSH_CONNECTION=127.0.0.1 54804 127.0.0.1 22
> TMPDIR=/var/folders/sl/v6txmh7n22q71grj631dvhz80000gp/T/
> SHLVL=0
> PWD=/Users/mac_user/projects/dpp2/app
> OLDPWD=/Users/mac_user
> _=/usr/bin/env

Where is this properties files located, so that I can eventually edit it?
Now I'm executing on localhost, but un the future it will be on remote machine, would there be a difference in the applied solution?

I execute the code below on every SHH command sampler, before the needed commands:

`cd path/to/folder; export PATH=path/folder:PATH`

But it is not reasonable, I need to have the result of this commands for all SSH command samplers.

I attempted to find the configuration file (returned with command env), but I couldn't find where is it located.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve you can either:

1. Add `--login` to your [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) executable, this way it will process everything from [.bashrc](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/bashrc-file-in-linux), [.bash_profile](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/what-is-the-purpose-of-bash_profile-file-under-user-home-directory-in-linux/) and so on

   [image]
2. Or switch to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and create the required [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) session manually using [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) language:

   ```
   def channel=session.openChannel('exec')
   channel.setPty(true)
   ```